# Get resources by int number

Tags: android, android-resources

I sometimes see this declarations in Android source code:

```
mContext.getString(2131361954);
Notification n = new Notification(2130837696, "123", System.currentTimeMillis());

// Example code - does not match together
```

I think the numbers are some resources from the project, right? Why sometimes people work with this numbers instead of using the R class? Is it faster or something else?

And how can I check which resource is assigned to that numbers? Is it possible to get number which is used if I only have the file or is this number random? Maybe with the file name or the MD5 hash of the file or something else?

Comment: Is this from actual Android source code, or the result of decompiling an app? If it is the result of decompiling, then the reason you see just numbers rather than identifiers is because the compiled code only has the numeric values, and can't reconstruct the original source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no performance difference, as all members of the R class are static and final, and are directly swapped in during compile time. This is equivalent to any code that uses R.x.y, so the performance is the same.

I would strongly recommend against using the numbers directly in your project as they may change during the addition, removal and modification of resources.

You can check the resource to which that number corresponds by converting it to hex, opening up the R.java file and searching for that hex number and seeing what it is assigned to.

You can also use `getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);` and pass it the ID at runtime to retrieve the file name.

Comment: I have a decompiled app where all resources are stored in the `public.xml` If I want to add a png now is it enough to add this line? `<public type="drawable" name="file_name" id="0xHEXNUMBER" />` Of course the hexnumber has to increased with the last number. Or do I have to add some more?

Comment: @Cilenco I have never heard of any app using a public.xml, so I can't advise on how to proceed here, since I have no idea how it is handled.